# jQuery with load and contains + next

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, load, contains

Im trying to make a ajax request (load) and get the content of a td.
My problem is that the sourcesite dont use any id's. So i have to determine the td with another option.

I can determine the wished div like this (on the sourcesite behind the "link")

```
$("#main-body").find("td:contains('Stichwort')").next().css("background-color", "#90EE90")
```

But how can I translate this to my `jQuery.load()`?

```
$("#ergebniss" + i).load(link + "td:contains('Stichwort')");
```

`:contains` isn't working and also I don't know how to implement `next()` into the load method?

-edit-
Following example is working fine for me (but is no soluting because the td position can change)

```
 $("#ergebniss"+i).load(link + "table:eq(0) td:eq(73)");
```

Comment: In that case it would be easier to get the whole HTML of the page and traverse it as you would the currently loaded DOM (which is what `load()` does anyway when you give it a selector). I'd also ensure that your AJAX request is working, as if this is a third party domain you may be blocked by the Same Origin Policy

Comment: You can directly try like this

$("#main-body").find("td:contains('Stichwort')").next().load(link)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did it this way: `var pageInhalt = getTheImportant(link);` then do something with pageInhalt and calling this `function getTheImportant(url) {
    var result;

    $.ajax({
        type:    "GET",
        url:     url,
        async:   false,
        success: function(data) {
          result = data;
        }
    });

    return result;
}`